# How to correct the model for a change in data collection methodology?

Tags: regression, mixed-model

I am modeling longitudinal data (sales at different stores across some span of months) with a mixed model. The data is collected by going to the physical store and annotating all the useful features (including sales). However with covid the amount of stores reached has decreased and we are kind of projecting the difference. Basically, the data collection methodolgy has changed. How can I take that into account in the model?
We have a good amount of data in the original methodology, how can we control for the temporary change in data collection?

More details:

- By projecting the sales we see some bumps in the dependent variable since we lose observations. We are estimating the total volume by projecting the sales of a lesser amount of stores.
- Our goal is to report coefficients or at least some metric of impact in sales of different features as store promotions and other features that affect a group of stores.
- By having less precise data I'm afraid the shift in volume might affect the estimation of coefficients if we don't apply any kind of control for that.

Comment: In what way has the methodology changed ? Is it just the volume has changed ? What exactly is your research question ?

Comment: @RobertLong I have updated the question with some extra details. Does that help?